# How to delete certain folders using batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to delete all folders, which are marked with the higher number than in the parameter.

e.g. If I type `batchname 20`, the batch file should delete folders, that are called `p21`, `p22`, `p23` and leave the folders, that are called `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `[...]`, `p20`.

I found this script online and tried it, but it only deletes everything but one folder:

```
for /D %%D in ("*") do (
    if /I not "%%~nxD"=="p%1" rd /S /Q "%%~D"
)
for %%F in ("*") do (
    del "%%~F"
```

How do I make this script work according the the above?

Comment: You need to isolate the number from the folder name and assign it to a variable. This can be done with the SET command. Then you can do a comparison with the IF command.

Answer (score 0):

This commented batch file can be used for this task.

```
@echo off
rem Is the batch file not called with at least one parameter?
if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF

rem Is the parameter string not a positive number?
for /F "delims=0123456789" %%I in ("%~1") do goto :EOF

rem Convert the number string to an integer and back to a number string
rem using an arithmetic expression and then check for equal strings. A
rem difference means that the number string was not in valid range of
rem 0 to 2147483647 or was with leading zeros resulting in interpreting
rem the number as octal number on conversion to integer.

set /A Number=%~1 2>nul
if not "%~1" == "%Number%" set "Number=" & goto :EOF

rem Search for non hidden directories in current directory starting
rem with letter P. For each found directory matching this simple
rem wildcard pattern use an arithmetic expression to convert the
rem number string without first character P to an integer and back
rem to a number string. Then compare case-insensitive the original
rem directory name with rebuild directory name to make sure that the
rem found directory has a name consisting really of just letter P and
rem a decimal number in range 0 to 2147483647 without leading zeros.
rem If this condition is true, compare the two numbers using an integer
rem comparison and remove the directory quietly and with all files and
rem subdirectories on having a number greater than the parameter number.

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /D %%I in (p*) do (
    set "Number=%%I"
    set /A Number=!Number:~1! 2>nul
    if /I "p!Number!" == "%%I" if !Number! GTR %~1 ECHO rd /Q /S "%%I"
)
endlocal
```

**Note:** There is an `ECHO` left to command `rd` to just output to console which directories would be deleted on running this batch file from within a command prompt window. Remove command `ECHO` after verification by starting the batch file with various numbers if the batch file really works as expected in the directory containing the folders `p1`, `p2`, ...

Here is also a single command solution for usage in a batch file without any validity checks and without usage of delayed environment variable expansion. It is faster than above script, but also much more susceptible to errors which is not good on recursively deleting folders in my opinion.

```
@for /D %%I in (p*) do @for /F "delims=Pp" %%J in ("%%I") do @if %%J GTR %~1 ECHO rd /Q /S "%%I"
```

Again the command `ECHO` needs to be removed to really remove the subdirectories with a number greater than the number passed to the batch file as first argument.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`